# (matlab matrix operation), Is it possible to get a group of value from matrix without loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I'm currently working on implementing a gradient check function in which it requires to get certain index values from the result matrix. Could someone tell me how to get a group of values from the matrix?

To be specific, for a result matrx res with size M x N, I'll need to get element res(3,1), res(4,2), res(1,3), res(2,4)...

In my case, M is dimension and N is batch size and there's a label array whose size is 1xbatch_size, [3 4 1 2...]. So the desired values are res(label(:),1:batch_size). Since I'm trying to practice vectorization programming and it's better not using loop. Could someone tell me how to get a group of value without a iteration?

Cheers.

--------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------

The only idea I found is firstly building a 'mask matrix' then use the original result matrix to do element wise multiplication (technically called 'Hadamard product', [see in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))). After that just get non-zero element out and do the sum operation, the code in matlab should look like:

temp=Mask.*res;

desired_res=temp(temp~=0); %Note: the temp(temp~=0) extract non-zero elements in a 'column' fashion: it searches temp matrix column by column then put the non-zero number into container 'desired_res'.

In my case, what I wanna do next is simply sum(desired_res) so I don't need to consider the order of those non-zero elements in 'desired_res'.

Based on this idea above, creating mask matrix is the key aim. There are two methods to do this job.

Codes are shown below. In my case, use accumarray function to add '1' in certain location (which are stored in matrix 'subs') and add '0' to other space. This will give you a mask matrix size [rwo column]. The usage of full(sparse()) is similar. I made some comparisons on those two methods (repeat around 10 times), turns out full(sparse) is faster and their time costs magnitude is 10^-4. So small difference but in a large scale experiments, this matters. One benefit of using accumarray is that it could define the matrix size while full(sparse()) cannot. The full(sparse(subs, 1)) would create matrix with size [max(subs(:,1)), max(subs(:,2))]. Since in my case, this is sufficient for my requirement and I only know few of their usage. If you find out more, please share with us. Thanks.

The detailed description of those two functions could be found on matlab's official website. [accumarray](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html#bt3682d-1_1) and [full](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html?searchHighlight=full%20sparse), [sparse](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html?searchHighlight=sparse).

```
% assume we have a label vector
test_labels=ones(10000,1);
% method one, accumarray(subs,1,[row column])
tic
subs=zeros(10000,2);
subs(:,1)=test_labels;
subs(:,2)=1:10000;
k1=accumarray(subs,1,[10, 10000]);
t1=toc % to compare with method two to check which one is faster

%method two: full(sparse(),1)
tic
k2=full(sparse(test_labels,1:10000,1));
t2=toc
```

Comment: What have  you tried so far?

Comment: Just build the indices and use them.

Comment: @Fl.pf. please check the update contents

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin cheers mate